# Display Sale Price Before Regular Price (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'd like to display the sale price of a product before the regular (discounted) price. I know this has something to do with `get_price_html`. By default, this outputs something like:

```
<del>regular price</del>
<ins>sale price</ins>
```

I want to change the output so it looks like this (basically, the two prices are shown in a different order):

```
<ins>sale price</ins>
<del>regular price</del>
```

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this in functions.php

```
if (!function_exists('my_commonPriceHtml')) {

function my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price) {
    $html_price = '<p class="price">';
    //if product is in sale
    if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price != 0)) {
        $html_price .= '<ins>' . wc_price($sale_price) . '</ins>';
        $html_price .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
    }
    //in sale but free
    else if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price == 0)) {
        $html_price .= '<ins>Free!</ins>';
        $html_price .= '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
    }
    //not is sale
    else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price != 0)) {
        $html_price .= '<ins>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</ins>';
    }
    //for free product
    else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price == 0)) {
        $html_price .= '<ins>Free!</ins>';
    }
    $html_price .= '</p>';
    return $html_price;
}

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_simple_product_price_html', 100, 2);

function my_simple_product_price_html($price, $product) {
if ($product->is_type('simple')) {
    $regular_price = $product->regular_price;
    $sale_price = $product->sale_price;
    $price_amt = $product->price;
    return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
} else {
    return $price;
}
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_price_html($price, $variation) {
$variation_id = $variation->variation_id;
//creating the product object
$variable_product = new WC_Product($variation_id);

$regular_price = $variable_product->regular_price;
$sale_price = $variable_product->sale_price;
$price_amt = $variable_product->price;

 return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
 }

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_minmax_price_html($price, $product) {
$variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price('min', true);
$variation_max_price = $product->get_variation_price('max', true);
$variation_min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
$variation_max_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);

if (($variation_min_price == $variation_min_regular_price) && ($variation_max_price == $variation_max_regular_price)) {
    $html_min_max_price = $price;
} else {
    $html_price = '<p class="price">';
    $html_price .= '<ins>' . wc_price($variation_min_price) . '-' . wc_price($variation_max_price) . '</ins>';
    $html_price .= '<del>' . wc_price($variation_min_regular_price) . '-' . wc_price($variation_max_regular_price) . '</del>';
    $html_min_max_price = $html_price;
}

return $html_min_max_price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it myself and this is my price.php code. You just need to add some css as per your need.

**First, remove the existing code**

```
'<p class="'.esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ).'">'.$product->get_price_html().'</p>';
```

**Then put this code :**

```
global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();

if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
    $discount = ($sale_price/$regular_price)*100;

echo    '<ul class="'.esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price')).'">
            <li class="sale_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$sale_price.'</li>
            <li class="regular_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$regular_price.'</li>
            <li class="disc">'.round($discount,0).'% Off</li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>';
} elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
    // Regular price min and max
    $min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' );
    $max_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max' );

    // Sale price min and max
    $min_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min' );
    $max_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max' );

    // The active price min and max
    $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min' );
    $max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max' );
    $var_discount = ($min_sale_price/$min_regular_price)*100;

echo    '<ul class="'.esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price')).'">
            <li class="sale_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$min_sale_price.'</li>
            <li class="regular_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'</span>'.$max_regular_price.'</li>
            <li class="disc">'.round($var_discount,0).'% Off</li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>';
    }
```

The output is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Price is come from `price.php` file in woocommerce plugin. inside this file there is function like

```
$price_html = $product->get_price_html();
```

You have to comment it and put following code instead of this function.

```
// Sale Price
<span class="price"><?php echo "Sale Price :". " " . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$product->get_sale_price(); ?></span>
// Regular Price
<span class="price"><?php echo "Regular Price :". " " . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$product->get_regular_price(); ?></span>
```

and add classes as per your requirements.